# Flutter and iOS native page mutual jump

Tags: ios, flutter

Excuse me, here is the native page of flutter jump iOS with navigation bar, I encountered a problem when returning to the flutter page.
Jump logic:

```
if ([@"jumpToiOSNativePages" isEqualToString:call.method] ) {

   NativeViewController *vc = [[NativeViewController alloc] init];

   FlutterViewController* controller = (FlutterViewController*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

   UINavigationController *chatNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

   controller.view.window.rootViewController = chatNav;

   [chatNav pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

Then when the `NativeViewController` clicks back:

```
 (void)leftbackOnClick {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NativeViewController *vc = [[NativeViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *chatNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

    vc.mainVC = (FlutterViewController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = chatNav;
```

Add @property (nonatomic,strong) FlutterViewController *mainVC in the NativeViewController.h class;
Set on return:
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = self.mainVC;